# Finding the heap usage of the process thread wise in qnx

Tags: multithreading, memory-leaks, heap-memory, qnx

My application running on a qnx machine is leading to serious memory leak over a period of time.It has 8 threads.I want to see a trend of heap usage by individual threads over a period of time to narrow down the problem. Using the flags available in pidin i am able to see stack usage trend alone.Is there any way to get the heap usage trend over a period of time ?

Answer (score 1):

The heap memory is common for entire process and hence it is not possible to know how much heap is used by individual threads.

Using the "showmem -lsh | grep processname" you could see the heap memory and by running it for over a period of time periodically , you could see the heap memory getting increased.

Maybe you can activate debug from malloc and try.

See: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/m/malloc.html?lang=jp